# Sticky Navgiation Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, parallax, sticky

I was wondering if you could help.

I am currently putting together a site that requires a parallax scroll and sticky navigation.

The navigation must start below image 1 (Blue) and then stick to the top in a fixed format after you've scrolled past image 1(blue).

I have tried many options and at present, I have got the navigation to stick to the top and then reappear once image1 (Blue) has been passed - but it starts at the top.

I have tried some jQuery plugins and they have not worked, could it be the way I have got my script formatted? As some is embedded directly into the page and not an external file?

Here is my link: http://bella-web.co.uk/sticky-nav/

and would love some feedback as to how I am going to get this to work.

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add navigation menu that starts in the middle of the page and sticks when it reaches the top using the jQuery plugin [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), the plugin doesn't just work out of the box, so please read the docs.

Comment: thanks very much, I tried out the waypoints and even with mimicking the example & couldn't get it to work. 

However, I just created a new div and under image 1 and then revamped the javascript I already had installed and it worked. 

But thank you for taking time to help.stuck it  

Ben.